# Usage of Offline Files Cache in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I need to use an Offline Files Cache API for C#.
I found this page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc296090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But I don't know which `COM` I need to include in the project.